# Constructing probability measures $(\xi_n)$ on $\mathbb N$ with a.s. increasing independent random sampling as $n \to \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I’m trying to come up with a sequence of probability measures $(\xi_n)_{n \geq 1}$ on $\mathbb N$ with the property that as $n \to \infty$, arbitrarily large independent sampling of $\mathbb N$ is a.s. increasing.

Here are the precise formulations. Suppose $(\xi_n)$ is our sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb N$. Let $k \geq 2$. Consider the set
$$
A_{k} = \{ (i_1, \ldots, i_k) \in \mathbb N^k: i_1 < \ldots < i_k\}
$$
consisting of all increasing $k$-tuples of positive integers. Let $\mu_{n,k} = \xi_n^{\otimes k}$ be the probability measure on $\mathbb N^k$ representing independent $k$-fold sampling of $\mathbb N$-valued $\xi_n$-distributed random numbers.

**My goal:** I want the probability measures $(\xi_n)$ to be chosen so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{n,k}(A_k)= 1$ for all $k \geq 2$.

I’m not sure that this is even possible, but I know certain constructions don’t work. For example, I found that it’s not enough to let $\xi_n = \sum_{i=1}^n p_{n,i} \delta_i$ for some strictly decreasing sequence $\{p_{n,1}, \ldots, p_{n,n}\}$ (where $\delta_i$ is the Dirac measure on $\{i\}$). Indeed, if we suppose that $\xi_n = Q_n \sum_{i=1}^n r^i \delta_i$ for some $r \in (0,1)$, $Q_n > 0$ a normalizing constant, we end up finding that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_{n,2}(A_2) = r/(1+r) < 1$. But maybe there’s a different way to choose decreasing $(p_{n,i})$ that get me what I want?

The idea was inspired by a similar problem, where instead of wanting our random sampling of $\mathbb N$ to be increasing, we simply want it to be non-repeating. This is much easier: here, $\xi_n = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_i$ does the trick, and the reason is quite simple intuitively: if we have a larger collection of integers to choose from, and the probability over these integers are uniformly distributed, it’s less likely that we’ll get repeating samples. I’m having trouble coming up with a similar heuristic that helps me figure out how to crack this somewhat tougher nut.

Any thoughts on how to construct these measures $\xi_n$, or proving that such a construction is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. If we have i.i.d. random variables $X_{n,1}, \dots, X_{n,k} \sim \xi_n$, then the conditional on the $X_{n,i}$ all being distinct, all orderings of the $X_{n,i}$ are equally likely, by symmetry. Hence the probability that $X_{n,1} < \dots < X_{n,k}$ can never be larger than $1/k!$.

Comment: Ah yes. It’s obvious. Thanks